# SQL to hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have two table : utilisateur and licence. they are joined by id_utilisateur, which is the primary key in utilisateur and foreign key in licence.

in sql i have :

```
SELECT distinct utilisateur.* from utilisateur
INNER JOIN licence on utilisateur.id_utilisateur = licence.id_utilisateur
where licence.activation=0 or licence.activation=1;
```

How can i do it with hibernate using criteria ?

here's what i have tried :

```
final Criteria criteria = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Utilisateur.class, "user")
                .createCriteria("user.listeLicence" , "licence")
                .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
                        .add(Projections.property("user.idUtilisateur"))
                        .add(Projections.property("licence.utilisateur")));
        liste = criteria.list();
```

Comment: Have you read the docs already? If not read them first and try it on your own. It is not that hard

Comment: Yes, i edit to post what have tried

Comment: And what is the problem you encounter with the current criteria?